# Node JS Get all iframes from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, iframe

I have a static webpage which I can't change and I need to get all iframes on this page. The iframes have no id's or name. They look like this

```
<iframe height="584" width="630" src="someurl" scrolling="auto" noresize="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

So, I can get the "main page" content with the module request but I don't know how to loop through it and find all iframe elements and their sources!

Hope you can help,

dunklesToast

Comment: Look into [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), it will help you parse and traverse an HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node module called [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) is a node-like jQuery alternative. You can load your content of the "main page" and then get all the iframes like this:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio')
var $ = cheerio.load(mainPageContent);

$('iframe').each(function(index, element) {
    var url = $(element).attr('src'); // --> Get the URL of the iframe

    // Do something with the URL of the iframe here
});
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you!